# How can I add space while decoding Morse code

Tags: c++, morse-code

I have made a program in c++ for encoding and decoding morse code.
My program is working and the decoded message is fine but without spaces is there any way to add space.[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string translateMorseCode(string sentence);
string decoceMorseCode (string sentence);
int main()
{
 string sentence;
 cout<<"Enter word or sentence: ";
 getline(cin,sentence);
 cout<<"\nMorse Code is:\n";
 //convert input message into morse
 cout<<translateMorseCode(sentence)<<endl;

 //copying morse code into decode string for decoding 
 string decode = translateMorseCode(sentence);
 cout<<"\nDecoding morse code is text"<<endl;
 //converting back ito text string
 cout<<decoceMorseCode (decode);
 return 0;
}


string decoceMorseCode (string sentence)
{

string delimiter = " ";
string decode ="";
int pos = 0;
string token;

while ((pos = sentence.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {
    token = sentence.substr(0, pos);

    if(token==".-")
    {
        decode.append("a");
    }
    else if(token=="-...")
    {
        decode.append("b");
    }

    else if(token=="-.-.")
    {
        decode.append("c");
    }
    else if(token=="-..")
    {
        decode.append("d");
    }
        else if(token==".")
    {
        decode.append("e");
    }
        else if(token=="..-.")
    {
        decode.append("f");
    }
        else if(token=="--.")
    {
        decode.append("g");
    }
    else if(token=="....")
    {
        decode.append("h");
    }
    else if(token=="..")
    {
        decode.append("i");
    }
    else if(token==".---")
    {
        decode.append("j");
    }
    else if(token=="-.-")
    {
        decode.append("k");
    }
    else if(token==".-..")
    {
        decode.append("l");
    }
    else if(token=="--")
    {
        decode.append("m");
    }
        else if(token=="-.")
    {
        decode.append("n");
    }
    else if(token=="---")
    {
        decode.append("o");
    }
 else if(token==".--.")
    {
        decode.append("p");
    }
    else if(token=="--.-")
    {
        decode.append("q");
    }
    else if(token==".-.")
    {
        decode.append("r");
    }
    else if(token=="...")
    {
        decode.append("s");
    }
    else if(token=="-")
    {
        decode.append("t");
    }
   else if(token=="..-")
    {
        decode.append("u");
    }
   else if(token=="...-")
    {
        decode.append("v");
    }
    else if(token==".--")
    {
        decode.append("w");
    }
    else if(token=="-..-")
    {
        decode.append("x");
    }
        else if(token=="-.--")
    {
        decode.append("y");
    }
    else if(token=="--..")
    {
        decode.append("z");
    }
    else if(token=="-----")
    {
        decode.append("0");
    }
        else if(token==".----")
    {
        decode.append("1");
    }
    else if(token=="..---")
    {
        decode.append("2");
    }
    else if(token=="...--")
    {
        decode.append("3");
    }
    else if(token=="....-")
    {
        decode.append("4");
    }
    else if(token==".....")
    {
        decode.append("5");
    }
    else if(token=="-....")
    {
        decode.append("6");
    }
        else if(token=="--...")
    {
        decode.append("7");
    }
    else if(token=="---..")
    {
        decode.append("8");
    }
    else if(token=="----.")
    {
        decode.append("9");
    }

    sentence.erase(0,pos + delimiter.length());

}

return decode ; // returnung decoded text 
}




//function convert input message into morse return Morse Code as String
string translateMorseCode(string sentence)
{
 string MorseCode="";
 for(int i=0;i<sentence.length();i++){
 switch (sentence[i]){
 case 'a':
 case 'A':
 MorseCode.append(".- ");
 break;
 case 'b':
 case 'B':
 MorseCode.append("-... ");
 break;
 case 'c':
 case 'C':
 MorseCode.append("-.-. ");
 break;
 case 'd':
 case 'D':
 MorseCode.append("-.. ");
 break;
 case 'e':
 case 'E':
 MorseCode.append(". ");
 break;
 case 'f':
 case 'F':
 MorseCode.append("..-. ");
 break;
 case 'g':
 case 'G':
 MorseCode.append("--. ");
 break;
 case 'h':
 case 'H':
 MorseCode.append(".... ");
 break;
 case 'i':
 case 'I':
 MorseCode.append(".. ");
 break;
 case 'j':
 case 'J':
 MorseCode.append(".--- ");
 break;
 case 'k':
 case 'K':
 MorseCode.append("-.- ");
 break;
 case 'l':
 case 'L':
 MorseCode.append(".-.. ");
 break;
 case 'm':
 case 'M':
 MorseCode.append("-- ");
  break;
 case 'n':
 case 'N':
 MorseCode.append("-. ");
 break;
 case 'o':
 case 'O':
 MorseCode.append("--- ");
 break;
 case 'p':
 case 'P':
 MorseCode.append(".--. ");
 break;
 case 'q':
 case 'Q':
 MorseCode.append("--.- ");
 break;
 case 'r':
 case 'R':
 MorseCode.append(".-. ");
 break;
 case 's':
 case 'S':
 MorseCode.append("... ");
 break;
 case 't':
 case 'T':
 MorseCode.append("- ");
 break;
 case 'u':
 case 'U':
 MorseCode.append("..- ");
 break;
 case 'v':
 case 'V':
 MorseCode.append("...- ");
 break;
 case 'w':
 case 'W':
 MorseCode.append(".-- ");
 break;
 case 'x':
 case 'X':
 MorseCode.append(".-- ");
 break;
 case 'y':
 case 'Y':
 MorseCode.append("-.-- ");
 break;
 case 'z':
 case 'Z':
 MorseCode.append("--.. ");
 break;
 case ' ':
 MorseCode.append(" ");
 break;
 case '1':
 MorseCode.append(".---- ");
 break;
 case '2':
 MorseCode.append("..--- ");
 break;
 case '3':
 MorseCode.append("...-- ");
 break;
 case '4':
 MorseCode.append("....- ");
 break;
 case '5':
 MorseCode.append("..... ");
 break;
 case '6':
 MorseCode.append("-.... ");
 break;
 case '7':
 MorseCode.append("--... ");
 break;
 case '8':
 MorseCode.append("---.. ");
 break;
 case '9':
 MorseCode.append("----. ");
 break;
 case '0':
 MorseCode.append("----- ");
 break;
}
}
 return MorseCode;// return Morse Code
}
```

Comment: no its not working getting same results

Comment: m pretty sure its not so smile :(

Comment: Please add text instead of screenshots.

Comment: i have explain at beginning how can i add space to separate all words in the result by decoceMorseCode function

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you use a double space in your morse output to **encode** a word boundary, but your **decoder** skips all spaces. It therefore skips double spaces too, which is why it doesn't know where to put a space in the decoded output.

Answer (score 1):

According to wiki:

> Each character (letter or numeral) is represented by a unique sequence of dots
>   and dashes. The duration of a dash is three times the duration of a dot. Each 
>   dot or dash is followed by a short silence, equal to the dot duration. The 
>   letters of a word are separated by a space equal to three dots (one dash), and 
>   the words are separated by a space equal to seven dots. The dot duration is the 
>   basic unit of time measurement in code transmission.[1] To increase the speed of 
>   the communication, the characters are encoded so the length of each character in 
>   Morse is approximately inversely proportional to its frequency of occurrence in 
>   English. Thus, the most common letter in English, the letter "E," has the 
>   shortest code, a single dot.

So in my opinion:
Two "\s" should be between words.
One "\s" between single char.

Comment: is don't get it  where to place "/s"

Comment: Which isn't actually the case. There's a `case ' ':` which handles word boundaries. (You can argue that it ignores newlines)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i tested my result with an online converter and result are same

Comment: @MSalters i have tried '' " is my code but not getting required result 
i used   decode.append(" ") ; below to     sentence.erase(0,pos + delimiter.length()); i get space after every char not after word

Answer (score 1):

@Neska gave you the basic answer but did not explain where the space gets interpreted.

When you get the tag decoded your logic should be able to detect the silence between the dots and dashes. Otherwise, it would not be able to determine where an individual character ends and the next character begins. That logic should detect the longer (seven dots long) interval between the end of a word and the beginning of the next work. Put in a special character (not a . or a dash) to be interpreted as a space in your morse code interpreter.

If you are interpreting text input and searching for the next delimiter (such as a space) in order to translate the dots and dashes, output the delimiters as well. That will put in the appropriate number of spaces

For example

```
.-^-^^-...^-.--
```

translates to

```
at^by
```

where the ^ character shows where the space should be.

Your code translates this as atby

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by myself and it was quite simple - I just added

```
else if (" ")
    {
        decode.append(" ");
    }
```

before the

```
 sentence.erase(0,pos + delimiter.length());
```